# How to get Sphinx's autodoc to omit the module name?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm having trouble controlling Sphinx's autodoc feature.

My directory structure is:

```
projname
+ projname
  __init__.py
  Scheduler.py containing class Scheduler
+ docs
  conf.py
  index.rst
```

conf.py contains:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../projname'))
```

And index.rst contains:

```
.. automodule:: Scheduler
```

This does what I want, except that the generated Scheduler class documentation comes out as:

```
class Scheduler.Scheduler()
...[all the methods etc documented correctly]¶
```

I could live with that, but in order to cross reference the class elsewhere, I have to refer to is as

```
:class:`Scheduler.Scheduler`
```

which leads to horribly ungainly documentation.

How do I persuade autodoc to omit the module name from the class documentation - I think it must be possible as other package documentation does seem to have it?

- Charles

Comment: Found the answer on the Sphinx google groups mailing list [I wish Google would search its own groups?]

For the references I can use the syntax:

   :class:`.Scheduler`

The HTML doesn't have the leading '.', and puts in the link correctly.  This also works with meth and attr links.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`..currentmodule`](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/desc.html#dir-currentmodule) directive will help you here.